# Android: Button ripple only shows if there is no background color under it?

Tags: android, background-color, ripple, rippledrawable

I have an `ImageView` with a ripple selector in the top corner of my screen. The ripple will not work for some reason.
Please take a look at my image!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwgsT.png (I need 10 reps to post an image -_-)

`View B` has a dark green background color. Once I remove this background color the ripple will work.

my `ripple_selector.xml`:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/button_highlight">
</ripple>
```

I'm setting the ripple on my ImageView like this:
`android:background="@drawable/ripple_selector"`

If I give the ripple selector a mask or a background it will work as well, but I don't want to mask the ripple. What could be the problem? Ty.

Comment: Ripple will draw itself over provided mask or on parent view's background. If parent view has transparent background the ripple won't draw. If you have a RelativeLayout with two children on top of each other, the top has ripple, the bottom obscures the ripple because the ripple is still drawn on the RelativeLayout's background and NOT directly below a view.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if this is a bug or supposed to be intended behavior of a ripple drawable, but I've concluded that if a ripple drawable is placed on top of a background color that's not in its own `View`/ `ViewGroup`, it won't be drawn.

Comment: This is intended behavior. Ripple with no mask draws itself over view's parent. If something (view B) obscures the parent, you won't see the ripple.